# ayuda con accumulator pattern python 3, mi output no es el que yo quisiera?

Tags: python, bucles

```
suma=0

for ex in range (1, 11):

  nuevo_balance=300

  suma += nuevo_balance

  print ('persona numero',ex,'tiene',nuevo_balance ,'$' )
```

Lo que quiero es que en el output la persona 1 tenga 300 y la segunda 600 y la tercera 900 y asi sucesivamente.

OUTPUT:

```
persona numero 1 tiene 300 $
persona numero 2 tiene 300 $
persona numero 3 tiene 300 $
persona numero 4 tiene 300 $
persona numero 5 tiene 300 $
persona numero 6 tiene 300 $
persona numero 7 tiene 300 $
persona numero 8 tiene 300 $
persona numero 9 tiene 300 $
persona numero 10 tiene 300 $
```

Comment: Buenas, solo tienes que cambiar en el print la variable nuevo_balance por suma, ya que en cada bucle for nuevo_balance lo pones a 300 y es en suma donde se acumula.

Comment: Hola Juan. Como te ha comentado @lDanny7, tu problema es probablemente un despiste ya que creas una variable acumuladora pero no la usas en el print. Estos *errores* son peliagudos porque no te das cuenta pero son bastante *simples*. No creo que una respuesta sea necesaria ya que este es un caso particular tuyo. La cerraré como no reproducible. Un saludo ^^